# Why is the relative angular momentum of quark+antiquark in a pion equal to zero?

Tags: angular-momentum, standard-model, pions

In a set of lecture notes provided by my lecturer, it says that a pion consists of a quark ($q$) and an antiquark ($\bar{q}$) with relative $L=0$. The negative parity and the fact that $S=0$ makes the pion a state with $J=0$ and odd parity, which is called a pseudoscalar.

Why is it that $L=0$? Why not $1$? or $2$?..

Comment: Of course, the relative angular momentum of the electron and proton in plain 'ole hydrogen (in the ground state) is also zero...

Comment: "Why not 1? or 2?"  They exist but they are not called pions.

Comment: What are they called then?

Comment: $a_1$ and $\pi_2(1670)$, respectively, [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson). Why don't you simply study the PDG listings? They are *all* there (mostly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pions are the lowest mass meson. There are two reason for this:

1. Their valence quark content is only up and down quarks, which are the lowest mass quarks.
2. They represent the lowest energy state of those quarks, part of which comes from having no angular kinetic energy (which you will recall from intro mechanics can be expressed as $L^2/(2I)$). Other angular momentum states would simple be more massive (and indeed we see those states in the form of $\rho$ and $b$ mesons).

   This is really the key: orbital angular momentum implies energy (which means mass).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From my understanding, a rho meson has the same quark content as a pi meson but the bound state has spin 1 instead of 0. And the b meson involves a bottom quark.

Comment: Then, if we had, say an up antidown combination with spin 0 and L=1, what particle would this be? And what is the value of L in the rho meson?

Comment: For question like that you should be looking in Particle Data Book. Go to pdg.lbl.gov (that is the Particle data Group's homepage). In addition to on-line access you can order some of there products. The Booklet is plenty for the sorts of question you've just asked.

Comment: *"And the b meson involves a bottom quark."* There is also an excited light quark state called $b$ (and one called $a$ for that matter) which is what i was referring to there. Again, see the PDG's listings.

Comment: @Lusmi98  To be pedantic, actually there is a 3rd reason that trumps the rest... Pseudoscalars  are "abnormally", "exceptionally" light, so, much lighter than their vector cousins, the *ρ* s, because they are the "pseudogoldstone bosons of dynamically broken chiral symmetry". Don't worry about it yet, but there is a theorem protecting their mass from being large....

Comment: @Dan Indeed, parton distributions of all mesons are not even available, and their wave functions are spectacularly simple than those of baryons. All mesons are virtually trivial combinations of S and L, with the odd admixture of glueballs. Pseudoscalars are special, in that one should think of them as quark bound states  second, and as pseudogoldstons first, but this is a much deeper story, adequately discussed in other questions... This one addresses their quark picture which is simple.

Comment: In truth I've only a vague understanding of mesons as pseudo-goldstone bosons, and the simple frame of this answer owes more to my having a simple understanding of the problem then to having made a careful choice to fit the audience.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t have to be! L=0 is simply the lowest-mass one.

By definition, a pion is a $J^{PC}=\mathrm{even}^{-+}$ light unflavored meson with I=1. With naive quark content that decomposes to S=0, L=even, and anything matching it is defined as a pion. Like [pi(2)(1670)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/contents_listings.html). Its actual quark content is a matter of debate, and it could be an exotic excitation.